# Why can't I concatenate these two arrays?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

This is the code (a [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) mutation):

```
export const CREATE_PANORAMAS = (state, panoramas) => {
  console.log('building.panoramas:', state.building.panoramas)
  console.log('panoramas:', panoramas)
  state.building.panoramas.concat(panoramas)
  console.log('result:', state.building.panoramas)
}
```

This the result with the respective logs:

```
[] // building.panoramas
[{ name: "", objectId: "5849133aac502e006c581b58" }] // panoramas
[] // result
```

Why aren't the two arrays concatenating?

Comment: `console.building.panoramas.concat` this looks odd to me, but I'm no expert in this

Comment: @AlexSzabó it was a typo. It wasn't in the actual code.

Comment: Did you tried `Array.prototype.push.apply(state.building.panoramas, panoramas)`?

Comment: [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is _immutable_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) - The concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays. **This method does not change the existing arrays**, but instead returns a new array.

One way to use concat would be to do the following

```
state.building.panoramas = state.building.panoramas.concat(panoramas)
```

Or you can simply

```
[].push.apply(state.building.panoramas, panoramas);
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you do not assign the result of the concatenation to a the `state.building.panoramas` array as indicated by @JaromandaX.

You can also use rest element, spread element, destructuring assignment to concatenate two or more arrays

```
[...state.building.panoramas] = [...state.building.panoramas, ...panoramas];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to assign state.building.panoramas.concat(panoramas) to something first, or you could directly put it on your 'result' line

sampleArray.concat(moreValues) *returns* the concatenated array, it doesn't concatenate 'moreValues' to sampleArray itself.